# Why does srcset resize image?

Tags: srcset

I'm having a weird behaviour using srcset and I'm having a hard time understanding it. I've done a CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYBvNM

The problem is that I have a set of images (that Shopify generates) of various sizes: 240px, 480px, 600px and 1024px. The problem is that those are the maximum sizes. This means that if a merchant uploads a smaller image (let's say 600px), the 1024px version will be 600px, not 1024px. I cannot know that in advance, so I'm forced to simply add all the sizes as a "best case":

```
<img
     src="my_1024x1024.jpg"
     srcset="my_240px.jpg 240w, my_480px.jpg 480w, my_600px.jpg 600w, my_1024px 1024w"
     sizes="(max-width: 35em) 100vh, 610px"
     >
```

The weirdness happen when the image is indeed smaller than the expected max size. When that the case, the browser correctly select the appropriate image (in this case, it would select the 1024 version on a 15' Retina), but as the image is actually smaller than 1024px (size that I've indicated), the browser is actually resizing the image to be smaller than its native resolution.

You can compare in the CodePen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYBvNM that those two images are the 1024px version, but in the one using srcset, the rendering is actually smaller than with src only. I would have expected that it would leave the image at its native resolution.

Could you please explain why does that?

THanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it works is that 'w' descriptors are calculated into 'x' descriptors by dividing the given value with the effective size from the `sizes` attribute. So for instance, if 1024w is picked and the size is 610px, then 1024/610 = 1.67868852459016x, and that is the pixel density of the image that the browser will apply. If the image is then not in fact 1024 pixels wide, the browser will still apply this same density, which will "shrink" the image, because that's the right thing to do in the valid case when the image width and 'w' descriptor match.

You have to make the descriptors match the resource width. When the user uploads an image, you can check its width and use that as the biggest descriptor in `sizes` (if it's smaller than 1024), and remove the descriptors that are bigger than the given image width.